# Master is out of sync - how to resync

Tags: git

A number of commits are missing from my Master branch.   I know there is a specific commit on develope that is where master should be.

This sounds very hacky but if I could just make Master be the same as that commit revision - it would be back to where it is supposed to be.

So it's a bit like checking of a branch from a specific commit - instead, I want make master be the same as a certain branch for a specific commit.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `master` to be at a commit with the hash `123456`, do this:

```
git checkout master
git reset 123456 --hard
```